# Liferay remove default welcome page from user group public and private pages

Tags: liferay

I have a user group associated with a site template1 for public pages 
and to a site template2 for private pages.
I have two publics pages and two privates pages.
Any user who connect get his own personal site public and private with the pages from site template1 (2 pages I've set up) plus welcome page and from site template2 (2 pages I've set up) plus welcome page.

How can I get rid of this welcome page automatically for all users belonging to the user group ?
I really don't need this welcome page.

Answer (score 2):

Check the "Default User Public (and Private) Layouts" section in [portal.properties](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/propertiesdoc/portal.properties.html#Default%20User%20Private%20Layouts). Override and change in `portal-ext.properties`.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. Note that there's also an "accept" button, a checkmark, to the left of the answer, which has the same meaning

Comment: Hi  user3158619, can you please share the detail about what you did ? Thanks, Tania